# Don't displayed MaterialButton in DialogFragment Android7

Tags: android, material-design

I have custom DialogFragment. This dialog have some message and round button 
On Android 8-10 all work correct, but Android 5-7 I don't see button, only buttons text
I try create layout with one button, result same

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">

<com.google.android.material.button.MaterialButton
    style="@style/ButtonOk"
   android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Button text"
    android:textColor="@color/colorTextBlack"
    app:cornerRadius="20dp"
    app:elevation="32dp"
    app:backgroundTint="@android:color/holo_green_light"
    app:strokeColor="@android:color/holo_red_dark"
    app:strokeWidth="1dp" />
```

```
    <style name="ButtonOk" parent="Widget.MaterialComponents.Button">
    <item name="android:layout_marginTop">28dp</item>
    <item name="android:layout_marginBottom">32dp</item>
    <item name="android:layout_width">200dp</item>
    <item name="android:letterSpacing">0</item>
    <item name="android:textSize">17sp</item>
    <item name="android:textAllCaps">false</item>
    <item name="cornerRadius">20dp</item>
    <item name="strokeColor">@color/colorAccent</item>
</style>
```

What wrong? Why this don't work correct on Android 5-7

it seems to me that on younger versions the backgroundTint and strokeColor parameters is ignored

Moreover, if I insert the same button in the layout of the fragment, then the button will be displayed normally

=====Added==== 
In my dialog I have transparent background

```
override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    setStyle(DialogFragment.STYLE_NORMAL, R.style.MyDialogTheme)
}

<style name="MyDialogTheme">
    <item name="android:background">#00ffffff</item>
</style>
```

If I comment setStyle(DialogFragment.STYLE_NORMAL, R.style.MyDialogTheme), button displayed, but my dialog is no longer transparent

Comment: try to add in your `MyDialogTheme` `parent="ThemeOverlay.MaterialComponents.Dialog"`

Comment: don't work when I add parent dialog isn't transparent and button not displayed